# Splitting a csv into multiple csv files by column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Trying to learn Python and managed to create a script that takes a csv, turns it into a data frame, changes the columns and then outputs a csv to the desired style.

Well what I need to do now is to be able to output multiple csvs based on the contents of my second column (first is the index, which I remove for output)

I have set up a parameter for unique data values and then a FOR loop to create filenames and output paths based on the unique data value.

But when I output the csv (data.to_csv), all 4 files are the same and unfiltered.

Here is my code

```
unique_code = data.import_code.unique() 
for importcode in unique_import_codes:     
    #print("%s" % importcode)             
    filename = importcode.replace(".","") + ".csv"   
    #print("%s" % filename)                
    path = r"C:/myrequiredpath/"     
    #print("%s" % path)                    
    data.to_csv(path+filename, index=False)
```

my data frame is called data
import_code is my second column (not an index)

any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `loc` to filter data:

```
unique_code = data.import_code.unique() 
for importcode in unique_import_codes:
    filename = importcode.replace(".","") + ".csv"
    path = r"C:/myrequiredpath/"
    data.loc[data.import_code==importcode].to_csv(path+filename, index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way:

```
filename =  r"C:/myrequiredpath/{}.csv"

data.groupby('import_code') \
    .apply(lambda g: g.to_csv(filename.format(g.name), index=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your loop do you do anything to select a subset of data. The last line

```
data.to_csv(path+filename, index=False)
```

Just writes out the unchanged data frame with a different filename each time.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to just export the file, each being a copy of the original dataframe with the unique values as a name, then I would go this route.

```
unique_values = set(data['column_of_interest'])

for value in unique_values:
    filename = value + ".csv"         
    path = r"C:/myrequiredpath/"                        
    data.to_csv(path+filename, index=False)
```

If you want each file to be an export of that subset of the data, then add this to your loop:

```
data[data['column of interest']==value]
```